# Save an html table into a file on server php

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-put-contents

I want to save an html table into an excel file, and save it on server with php. I'm sending the html table to php using XMLHttpRequest :

```
var excel_data = document.getElementById('result-table').innerHTML;

   console.log(excel_data);
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          =
        }
    };
     var donn = "filt="+ excel_data;

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "saveToServer.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(donn);
```

And here's how I retrieve the table fom php side:

```
$data = $_POST["filt"];
file_put_contents('attachments/excel.xls', $data, FILE_APPEND);
```

Here's a part  of the html table:

```
<h2 id="searchResultTitle">Today's alarms</h2><table id="dataTable" class="wrap" 
style="position:relative;">
<tbody><tr><th>Raise date</th>
<th>Site</th>
<th>Severity</th>
<th>Alarm</th>
<th>Detail</th>
</tr><tr>
<td style="white-space:nowrap">2020-07-23 14:00:06</td>

<!--Issue happens here-->

<td style="font-size:11px;"><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="siteDetail.php? 
id=A16X647_HAI EL BADR&amp;fich=huawei-bss-deb-alarm">A16X647_HAI EL BADR</a></td>
<td style="color:red;">Critical</td><td>Commercial Power Down _Main Power Down_</td>
<td><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="alarmDetail.php?id=90455861&amp;fich=huawei- 
bss-deb-alarm">More</a></td></tr>
...
```

and here's the `excel.xls` content:

```
<h2 id="searchResultTitle">Today's alarms</h2><table id="dataTable" class="wrap" 
style="position:relative;">
<tbody><tr><th>Raise date</th>
<th>Site</th>
<th>Severity</th>
<th>Alarm</th>
<th>Detail</th>
</tr><tr>
<td style="white-space:nowrap">2020-07-23 14:00:06</td>
<td style="font-size:11px;"><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="siteDetail.php? 
id=A16X647_HAI EL BADR
```

The main issue that I've been struggling and I don't understand why is why the writing stops at the first `<a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="siteDetail.php? id=A16X647_HAI EL BADR`

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: the last `</tr` is wrong type or no?

Comment: I just pasted a portion of the table, because the content is somehow long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the data like a query string but the `excel_data` variable contains illegal characters (the `&`) so at your server script the data received is wrong.

```
var donn = "filt="+ excel_data;

xmlhttp.open("POST", "saveToServer.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(donn);
```

The server is receiving:

```
filt=<h2 id="searchRe.....HAI EL BADR&amp;fich=huawei-bs.....
```

Wich is translated as two variables:

```
filt = "<h2 id="searchRe.....HAI EL BADR"
amp;fich = "huawei-bs..."
```

You need to encode your table string to avoid this.

```
var donn = "filt="+ encodeURIComponent(excel_data);
```